# DataFrame from Tuples

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

I am trying to create a Dataframe from a list of tuples, but I am receiving the error list' object has no attribute 'toDF'. How can I avoid this error.
(https://www.gutenberg.org/files/63207/63207-0.txt)

```
with open('/files/63207-0.txt', 'r') as content_file:
material = content_file.read()

material = remove_white_spaces(normalize_text(content))

beginning_string = 'Introduction To Book' 
end_string = 'End of Book'
real_material = material[material.find(beginning_string)+len(beginning_string):material.rfind(end_string)]

Chapters = re.split(" Chapter [0-9]+ ", actual_content, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1:]

save_data = []
for i in range(1,1+len(chapters)):
save_data.append((i,chapters[i-1]))


Get the dataframe from a list of tuples with columns ["page_number", "text"]
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import Row
data = sc.parallelize(save_data)
data_converted = data.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[1], x[1])
schema = StructType([StructField("chapter"), StringType(), True), StuctField("text"), StringType(), True)

 df = SqlContext.createDataFrame(data_converted, schema)
 df.show(5)

Binning using Bucketizer

splits = [0, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, float("inf")]
bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=splits, inputCol="chapters", outputCol="buckets")
df_buck = bucketizer.transform(df)
df_buck.show(20)
```

Comment: what a bad code , use your `RDD`object ,not `list`

Answer (score 0):

If your list `save_data` looks something similar to this `[(1,2),(3,5)]`. Like a list which has tuples, you can easily create a dataframe using Pandas. Obviously, list will not have any attribute 'toDF'. DataFrames are objects of Pandas module.
This is how you can achieve your results:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(save_data, columns=["page_number", "text"])
```

With PySpark DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
df = spark.createDataFrame(save_data)
print(df)
```

Comment: A pandas dataframe does not work with my bucketizer. It is also from a text file.

Comment: Okay, I will just fit the answer with pySpark.

Comment: @DavidFrost - please tell us what "DataFrame" means in your context. Its commonly used for pandas. If you give us the context, we don't have to guess.

Comment: @tdelaney I just fixed it.

Comment: @Naazneen Jatu I received an 'str' object has no attribute '_jsc' error when I used this coding.